# i tried to define string end function in K&R excercises

Tags: c, pointers

i tried to define `strend(s,t)` function which returns **1** if string t at the end of s string and **zero** otherwise , this is my code .

```
typedef enum state
{
    Not_occured ,
    occured
}State;
char a[]="Hello world zone";
char b[]="ne";
int main(void)
{
    int x = 0 ;
    x =  strend(a,b);
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}

int strend(char *s, char *t)
{
    while(*++s);
    while(*++t);
    while(*t-- == *s--)
        if(!(*t))
            return occured;
    return Not_occured;
}
```

**modified code**

```
int strend(char *s, char *t)
{
    char *ptr = s;
    while(*++s);
    while(*++t);
    while(*t-- == *s--)
        if(s == ptr)
            return occured;
    return Not_occured;
}
```

why prefix worked here  `while(*++s);` , `while(*++t);` and postfix doesn't work?

Comment: Looks like you're probably dereferencing `t` after it's gone out of the bounds of the array.

Comment: Think about what `if (!(*t))` is supposed to be checking.

Comment: I would establish the length of each string, then do a simple for loop comparing the  relevant characters.

Comment: The prefix code `while(*++s);` ***doesn't*** actually work. It assumes that there's at least one non-NUL character in the string. If you define a string `b[] = "";` and use the loop, the code is likely to crash, or at least behave badly. The correct way to write the loop is `while(*s) s++;`

Comment: @user3386109 A blank string still has at least one character: a null byte.  If you run `sizeof b` in your example you should get 1.

Comment: @dbush I don't think you understood my comment. Are you claiming that the prefix code works with a blank string?

Comment: @user3386109 You're right, I misunderstood.  It will run past the end of the array if the string is blank.

Comment: @mohamedtarek The code has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So even though it seems to work (for the example in the question), it doesn't actually work. That's a hard concept for new C programmers to grasp, but it's very important if you want to be successful as a C programmer. Just because your code passes one test doesn't mean it's right.

Comment: The bottom line is that both the prefix code `while(*++s);` and the postfix code `while(*s++);` are wrong. The correct code is `while(*s) s++;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if(!(*t))` assumes there is a nul character before the first character in the string. Not only is this an incorrect assumption, but it also tries to access memory outside of the array bounds.

Also, `while(*t-- == *s--)`...What happens when the 2 strings are identical or `t` is longer than `s`?

Here's a simple solution:

```
int strend(char *s, char *t) {
    if (s == NULL || t == NULL) return Not_occured;

    size_t s_len = strlen(s);
    size_t t_len = strlen(t);

    if (t_len <= s_len) {
        return 0 == strcmp(&s[s_len - t_len], t) ? occured : Not_occured;
    }
    return Not_occured;
}
```

---

Since it's now clearer that the original question is about the pre- and post-fix operations, I've updated.

First, understand the difference between the two:

```
int x = 1;
printf("%d", x++);
// Prints 1 because x is evaluated before the inc
x = 1;
printf("%d", ++x);
// Prints 2 because x is evaluated after the inc
```

Now, some operator precedence:

```
postfix > dereference
prefix == dereference, right-to-left assoc.
```

What happens with `*s++`:

1. `s++` is evaluated - this first stores the current value of `s` (let's call that `s0`), then increments `s`
2. `s0` is dereferenced

This is the same as:

```
char *s0 = s;
s += 1;
char c = *s0;
```

What happens with `*++s`:

1. `s` is incremented
2. `s` is dereferenced

This is the same as:

```
s += 1;
char c = *s;
```

Hope that makes sense.